# Reduce Ubuntu partition from the left (dual-boot)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted, 22.04

As shown on the attached picture, I have dual boot with Windows 10 (p3) and Ubuntu 22.04 (p5). In between of the two partitions I have a temporary partition (p4) labeled as TEMP. I would like to decrease windows partition (p3) from right to left, as well as reduce the size of Ubuntu partition (p5) from left to right in order to increase the volume of TEMP.

1. is it **safe to do** this operation with Gparted live boot such that Windows and Ubuntu will boot and operate correctly?
2. Should I decrease Windows partition with Windows Disk Manager (because it is encrypted with BitLocker) ?

[Gparted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdcQ1.png)

**EDIT**

For those wondering for the final solution: it worked perfectly with the below procedure :)

Comment: Only use Windows tools for the NTFS partitions and use Linux tools like gparted for the Linux partitions. Since bitlocker, not even sure gparted would work on your Windows partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Resizing partitions always has a risk. Therefor the advise is to always make backups.
   2) Yes, resize your `Windows` partition in `Windows`.
   You can never resize partition on their left side. Reduce them on the right and then move them to the left. In your case move your Ubuntu partition to the right, so you create space to enlarge your Temp partition.You don't have to move your `Windows` partition after decreasing its size ( because it is done on the right ).
   So: 
   Reduce your `Windows` partition in `Windows`. All the other actions you can do with `GParted`. 
   Reduce your `Ubuntu` partition ( with `GParted`).
   Move your `Ubuntu` partition to the right.
   Move your `Temp` partition to the left.
   Extend your `Temp` partition with the free space you created.
   To be sure make a note with the UUID's of the partitions before starting the operations, and check them after the operations. Because your not adding or deleting partitions I don't think they will change.

Comment: Thank you so far. I also thought that I dont need to move Windows partition. But on Ubuntu partition, do you mean I should decrease the partition on the right side and **move it to the right** s.th. there is space on the left of Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer for the step by step procedure.